# Translate Multiple Images from iPhone4 - iPhone5

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I wanted to migrate my app from iPhone4-iPhone5.
When i Googled i found that i need to change the launch image to Default-568h@2x.
Everything is working great until now.Only when i navigate to another view wherein i have 3 different images.These images are not wellFitted for iPhone 5 screens.

The first Image is of Size 480*480
The Second Image is of Size 320*65 
& Third Image is of Size 320*65

How do i set the sizes to match the image as it appears with iPhone4.

[image]

Thank You 
Best Regards.

Comment: you should use autolayout constraints...so that it will work properly for both screen sizes.

Comment: @Xman : Please check the edited question.Do you mean this ?? It is the Default Value. If yes Then please let me know which line to be selected and deselected.

Comment: try to enable the autosizing height also

Comment: @ernaidu : Probably you are saying the same thing Bhavesh has answered.If so, Do i need to do that for all the three images ??

Comment: Yes do it for all the images

Comment: @ernaidu : Working Great !! But the 2nd image seems to be too small.What size do i need to have it.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you @iCode AtApple

Comment: If i resize the dimensions of second image though it appears to be small compared to the UIIMageview it is contained within. i.e. a white background appears on the second image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

[image]

i hope helpful you........

Comment: Bhavesh : It was not supposed to be for all the three images, and so i was not able to figure out why the second image was not seen properly.It was different for all the three and it is working really good. But i still accept your answer as you gave me a hint to proceed. Thank You.